# How to draw this figure in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, asymptote

I am using Geogebra. When I export to LaTeX, Geogebra does not support 3D shapes, only 2D shapes. I need someone to explain to me how to draw this shape in LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: It  would be great if you explained what it is meant to represent, I don't think it's quite self explanatory (except for the axes, of course).

Comment: In any case, you probably want the tikz-3dplot package to set the coordinate system and rotation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the future, please provide some code you have tried and explicitly present the abstract problem you are stuck with.

Here is a suggestion to draw what you present. It is not very robust since it will need you to change by hand a lot of coordinates in case you want to change the position and the radius of the black circle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{3d}
    \usetikzlibrary{through}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y = 0]
        \draw[orange] (0, 0) circle (1cm);
    \end{scope}
    
    \draw[densely dotted, red] (0, 0, -.8) -- (1, 0, -.8) -- (1, 0, 0);
        
    \begin{scope}[%
        plane x = {({sqrt(1/1.64)}, 0, -{.8*sqrt(1/1.64)})},
        plane y = {(0, 1, 0)},
        canvas is plane,
    ]
        
        \coordinate (A) at ({sqrt(1.64)}, 0.3);
        \draw[densely dotted, red] (sqrt{1.64}, 0) -- (A);
        \draw (1, 0) -- (A);
        \node[draw, circle through = (A)] at (1, 0) {};
        
    \end{scope}
    
    \draw[red, -Latex] (-2, 0, 0) -- (2, 0, 0);
    \draw[blue, -Latex] (0, -2, 0) -- (0, 2, 0);
    \draw[green, -Latex] (0, 0, 2) -- (0, 0, -2);
    
    \fill[black] (1, 0, 0) circle (.02cm)
                 (0, 0, -.8) circle (.02cm)
                 (1, 0, -.8) circle (.02cm)
                 ({sqrt(1/1.64)}, 0, -{.8*sqrt(1/1.64)}) circle (.02cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

**EDIT**

As specified above, the proposed code is not robust to a change in the coordinates of the circle's center.
The following code then allows the user to choose the center of the circle and the height of the point it passes through.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{3d}
    \usetikzlibrary{through}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    pics/myCircle/.style n args = {3}{%
        code = {%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\orientation}{ifthenelse(#2 <= 0, -1, 1)}      
        
            \draw[densely dotted, red] (0, 0, #2) -- (#1, 0, #2) -- (#1, 0, 0); 
            \begin{scope}[%
                plane x = {({\orientation*(#1/#2)*sqrt(1/(1 + (#1*#1)/(#2*#2)))}, 0, {\orientation*sqrt(1/(1 + (#1*#1)/(#2*#2)))})},
                plane y = {(0, 1, 0)},
                canvas is plane,
            ]
                \coordinate (A) at ({sqrt(#1*#1 + #2*#2)}, #3);
                \draw[densely dotted, red] ({sqrt(#1*#1 + #2*#2)}, 0) -- (A);
                \draw (1, 0) -- (A);
                \node[draw, circle through = (A)] at (1, 0) {}; 
            \end{scope}
            
            \fill[black] (#1, 0, 0) circle (.02cm)
                         (0, 0, #2) circle (.02cm)
                         (#1, 0, #2) circle (.02cm)
                         ({\orientation*(#1/#2)*sqrt(1/(1 + (#1*#1)/(#2*#2)))}, 0, {\orientation*sqrt(1/(1 + (#1*#1)/(#2*#2)))}) circle (.02cm);
        },
    },%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y = 0]
        \draw[orange] (0, 0) circle (1cm);
    \end{scope}
        
    \draw[red, -Latex] (-2, 0, 0) -- (2, 0, 0);
    \draw[blue, -Latex] (0, -2, 0) -- (0, 2, 0);
    \draw[green, -Latex] (0, 0, 2) -- (0, 0, -2);
    
    \draw pic {myCircle = {1}{-.8}{.3}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice work done...